# GWT CellTree Search: Highlighting the searched node

Tags: gwt, gwt2

I am working on search functionality on GWT CellTree.

I have a cellTree with 4 levels. Namely, Root->Session->Uproc->Batch.

What I need to do is, when I get the searched node from the DB along with its parent, I need to expand its parent and highlight the node.

I am able to expand the parent node but how do I highlight the searched node?

Please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to select the object in your `SelectionModel`.

If that's not what you want, and you only want some other kind of highlighting, it gets tricky: you have to somehow communicate to your `Cell` that the specific value has to be drawn with an highlighted state, and then have the cell redrawn.
The first part depends on how you architectured your code; for the second part, you have to get a handle on the `TreeViewModel.NodeInfo` instance (or if you used a `TreeViewModel.DefaultNodeInfo`, on its `AbstractDataProvider`) for the *parent* of the highlighted node, so that you can trigger a redraw of the children list (where the highlighted item is). It again depends how you did it exactly, but you have to somehow make a call to the `HasData`'s (representing the list o children) `setRowData`, passing it the exact same data as is already displayed (but it's enough to trigger a redraw, so that the `Cell` will generate the *highlighted state* for the item).

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

You can highlight searched node by giving it css.
Here is the css:

```
.selected_tree_node {
    font-weight:  bold;
}
```

Apply this css to your node:

```
yourNode.setStyleName("selected_tree_node");
```

Comment: There's no _node_ in a `CellTree`.